# Javascript XML reading problem

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm having problems reading an XML local input. The weird thing is that this code works perfectly when the XML is located on a server(This is desktop, by the way, so no SOP problems).  I can't figure this out for the life of me, and I've been staring at it, trying different things for a couple of hours.

And another question: does the XML document need a css sheet to be properly read? I would imagine that it doesn't, but I don't know too much about it.

```
function verify()
{                   
    zipObj = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    zipObj.open("GET", "KMSY.xml", false);
    zipObj.onreadystatechange = function() {

            if (zipObj.readyState === 4) {

                 zipXML = zipObj.responseXML;
                 read(zipXML);
            } 
            else {
             document.getElementById("notice").innerHTML = zipObj.readyState;
            }
    }   
    zipObj.send();
}

function read(zipXML)
{
    var temp = zipXML.getElementsByTagName("temp_f")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

    document.getElementById("notice").innerHTML = temp;
}
```

Comment: > does the XML document need a css sheet to be properly read? ... CSS is for formatting documents for display in the browser. XML is a generic data interchange metaformat. Apples and oranges.

Answer (score 1):

Import the XML file to a local server, AJAX obviously needs the XML files to be on web server in order to parse them, or so my humble experience tells me.

You might also want to add the compatibility code for other XML requests into your code.

`new XMLHttpRequest()` for all browser and IE 8+

`new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")` IE prior to 8